# ASP MVC MaxLength(value) attribute allows value 1 characters if applied for string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I was using [MaxLength(value)] for view model Email address field with [EmailAddress] attribute. And found that email's with value+1 characters path validation process.

Answer (score 1):

Try StringLength attribute for this purpose.

```
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
public string Email{ get; set; }
```